# SQL: Detect whether an existing view supports INSERTs or UPDATEs

Tags: sql-server, sql-insert, sql-view

I have an application that allows users to define their own views in SQL and later have the application generate metadata about that view. This is mostly really easy as `information_schema.columns` tells me what the columns/types the view uses.

However, is there a way to find out whether the view can accept INSERT or UPDATE queries without doing something horrible like parsing the SQL myself or doing a test INSERT and checking for errors/rolling back the transaction?

Comment: "I have an application that allows users to define their own views in SQL" - really?

Comment: ...and later have the application generate metadata about that view, yes, last bit is the important bit

Comment: By users I mean admins configuring an instance of the application. Yes, it is dangerously close to becoming an inner platform.

Comment: Probably you have to perform test insert (without values or with default values) while validating SQL view after creating/updating it (you need to validate it anyway, correct?). You will fail views, allowing update of only some columns - but most likely such views should not be updated anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming SQL Server here, YMMV with other RDBMS products...

Assuming you're not using INSTEAD OF triggers, there is no flag or query that indicates whether a view is updatable or not, probably because a view can be updatable for certain classes of updates but not others.

Per [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx):

> Updatable Views
>
> You can modify the data of an underlying base table
>   through a view, as long as the following conditions are true:
>
> - Any modifications, including UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements,    must reference columns from only one base table.
> - The columns being    modified in the view must directly reference the underlying data in    the table columns.
> - The columns cannot be derived in any other way,    such as through the following: An aggregate function: AVG, COUNT,    SUM, MIN, MAX,
>     GROUPING, STDEV, STDEVP, VAR, and VARP.
> - The column    cannot be computed from an expression that uses other columns.    Columns that are formed by using the set operators UNION,
>     UNION ALL,    CROSS JOIN, EXCEPT, and INTERSECT amount to a
>     computation and are    also not updatable.
> - The columns being modified are not affected by    GROUP BY, HAVING, or DISTINCT clauses.
> - TOP is not used anywhere in    the select_statement of the view together with the WITH CHECK OPTION    clause.
>
> The previous restrictions apply to any subqueries in the FROM
>   clause of the view, just as they apply to the view itself. Generally,
>   the Database Engine must be able to unambiguously trace modifications
>   from the view definition to one base table. For more information, see
>   Modify Data Through a View.

So you might have a view that is based off a JOIN, where certain updates (involving only one base table) were legal, while others (involving multiple base tables) were not.

Comment: Thanks, that was the impression I got and makes sense.